# Login the registered users after account activation without fosuserbundle

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, twig, registration

I am trying to register (with email confirmation) and log in my users without using FOSUserBundle.

I took the idea from this video : https://www.grafikart.fr/tutoriels/confirmation-compte-824

what I have done for now:

> 1-a user register
>
> 2-an email is sent to the user for activation
>
> 3-if the user hit the link activate confirmation_token=null and
>   enabled =true

**BUT**

I don't know how to test in the login function and add the condition confirmation_login=null, to let just the activated account to log in.

this security.yml

```
encoders:
        AppBundle\Entity\User: bcrypt

    providers:
        db_provider:
            entity:
                class: AppBundle\Entity\User
                property: username

    firewalls:
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            anonymous: ~
            provider: db_provider
            form_login:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /


    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

this is my registrationController:

```
/**
 * @Route("/register")
 * @param Request $request
 * @Template()
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
 public function registerAction(Request $request)
 {
    $user = new User();
    $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $password = $this->get('security.password_encoder')
            ->encodePassword($user, $user->getPlainPassword());
        $user->setPassword($password);


        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();

        $confirmationToken = $user->getConfirmationToken();
        $username = $user->getUsername();
        $userId = $user->getId();

        $subject = 'Account activation';
        $email = $user->getEmail();
      /*  $renderedTemplate = $this->render('AppBundle:Register:registrationConfirmed.html.twig', array(
            'username' => $username,
            'confirmationToken' => $confirmationToken
        ));*/
        $message = (new \Swift_Message('Hello Email'))
            ->setSubject($subject)
            ->setFrom($this->container->getParameter('mailer_user'))
            ->setTo($email)
            ->setBody(
            $this->renderView(
                'AppBundle:Register:registrationConfirmed.html.twig', array('id' => $userId,'username' => $username,'confirmationToken' => $confirmationToken)), 'text/html');

        $this->get('mailer')->send($message);


        $this->addFlash('success', 'Genus created!');
       return $this->redirectToRoute('login');
    }

    return $this->render('AppBundle:Register:register.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
}


 /**
  * @Route("/confirm/{id}/{confirmationToken}", name="confirmation_path")
  */
public function confirmAction(Request $request, $id,$confirmationToken)
 {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $repository = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:User');
    //$confirmationToken = $user->getConfirmationToken();

    $user = $repository->findUserByIdAndConfirmationToken($id,$confirmationToken);

    if (!$user)
    {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('We couldn\'t find an account for that confirmation token');
    }
      else
      {

     $user= $repository->updateConfirmationTokenAfterValidation($id,$confirmationToken);

    // $user->setEnabled(true);
    // $user->setConfirmationToken(null);
    //$em->persist($user);
    // $em->flush();
      }
    return $this->redirectToRoute('login');
}
```

and this is the link in the email to activate the account:

```
<a href="{{ url('confirmation_path', {'id': id, 'confirmationToken': confirmationToken }  ) }}">Activate</a>
```

**and for login, I a using the loginAction, So how can I test here if confirmToken=null to let only the registered users to login**

```
/**
 * @Route("/login",name="login")
 */


 public function loginAction()
    {
        $helper = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');

        return $this->render('AppBundle:Login:login.html.twig', [
            // last username entered by the user (if any)
            'last_username' => $helper->getLastUsername(),
            // last authentication error (if any)
            'error' => $helper->getLastAuthenticationError(),
        ]);
    }
```

my login.html.twig

```
<form action="{{ path('login') }}" method="post">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">{{ 'label.username'|trans }}</label>
                <input type="text" id="username" name="_username"  class="form-control"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">{{ 'label.password'|trans }}</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                <i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{ 'action.sign_in'|trans }}
            </button>
        </form>
```

**Update**

I have implemented Userchecker and it works (I don't know if it's the better way or not)

```
 public function checkPostAuth(UserInterface $user)
    {
        if (!$user instanceof AppUser) {
            return;
        }

        if (!$user->getIsActive()) {
            throw new \Exception("ce membre n'est pas actif");
        }

    }
```

Comment: In your loginAction, get the entity manager service. Then retrieve the account via the mail given in the form. Check then (if the mail is used in an existing account) the confirmToken in the retrieved entity if confirmToken is null

Comment: What you need is to create your own Guard Authenticator and use it in your `security.yml`. To create it, follow the instructions from here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html